# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, routes, webforms

I am receiving the rather self explanatory error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*).

The issue is due to `*` in the request URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/Search/test*/0/1/10/1
```

This url is used to populate a search page where 'test*' is the search term and the rest of the url relates to various other filters.

Is there an easy way to allow these special characters in the URL? I've tried modifying the `web.config`, to no avail.

Should I manually encode / decode the special characters?
Or is there a best practice for doing this, I would like to avoid using query strings. - but it may be an option.

The application itself is a `c# asp.net` webforms application that uses routing to produce the nice URL above.

Comment: Does your page have `ValidateRequest=false` at the top?

Comment: I don't know for what reason the website was internally trying a redirection which was creating a URL like 'http://localhost/://localhost/myWebsiteName/' which was giving me the same error. I don't know why ASP.net pipeline considers it a dangerous request URL.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The `*` character is not allowed in the path of the URL, but there is no problem using it in the query string:

```
http://localhost:3286/Search/?q=test*
```

It's not an encoding issue, the `*` character has no special meaning in an URL, so it doesn't matter if you URL encode it or not. You would need to encode it using a different scheme, and then decode it.

For example using an arbitrary character as escape character:

```
query = query.Replace("x", "xxx").Replace("y", "xxy").Replace("*", "xyy");
```

And decoding:

```
query = query.Replace("xyy", "*").Replace("xxy", "y").Replace("xxx", "x");
```

Comment: The "xxx" "xxy" "xyy" game is pretty clever. You might want to elaborate on the logic behind that so as not to confuse readers.

Comment: The request was to use it in the `PATH` and not in the querystring.

Comment: I ran into the same scenario where one of my parameters was a URL.  Even when properly URL encoded, I would get this error.  I finally just base64 encoded the parameter (and decode in my api) which was much easier than trying to figure out what was going on.  Probably a better choice that implementing your own replace routine as well.

Comment: Can't you use `aa` <=> `a` and `ab` <=> `*` as a simpler encoding scheme?

Comment: For now this saved me, Thanks, But in proper time I want to check this advise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/603962/1830909 and I'll be glade if hear your thought.

Comment: Why not use some [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) characters? A lot safer...

Answer (score 350):

If you're using .NET 4.0 you should be able to allow these urls via the web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
            requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

Note, I've just removed the asterisk (*), the original default string is:

```
<httpRuntime 
          requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client) for more details.

Comment: Any way to do this using an mvc attribute on an action so I don't have to turn this off for the entire app?  Similar to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1540976/298758

Comment: @longda: Perhaps try wrapping it with a <location path="my/path"> element for the url you need. Using reflection would be reasonably simple from a global perspective, but I'm not sure about setting it on a per controller/action basis. Maybe start a question?

Comment: It's just not working on ASP.net MVC project, receiving run process to determine layout in viewStart got this error: Illegal character in path.

Comment: the default list etc. is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 13):

For me, I am working on  .net 4.5.2 with web api 2.0,
I have the same error, i set it just by adding  requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
in the requestPathInvalidCharacters you have to set not allowed characters else you have to remove characters that cause this problem.

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
     <pages  >
      <namespaces>
     ....
 </namespaces>
    </pages> 
  </system.web>
```

**Note that it is not a good practice, may be a post with this parameter as attribute of an object is better or try to encode the special character.
-- After searching on best practice for designing rest api, i found that in search, sort and paginnation, we have to handle the query parameter like this

```
/companies?search=Digital%26Mckinsey
```

and this solve the problem when we encode & and remplace it on the url by %26
any way, on the server we receive the correct parameter Digital&Mckinsey

this link may help on best practice of designing rest web api
https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9

Comment: I think that is a good practice to do this actually. The protection against malformed input should be in the code.

Answer (score 9):

You should encode the route value and then (if required) decode the value before searching.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Do you mean effectivley doing a replace on items such as * and then replacing them back when you are reading it?

Comment: Can you show a code example of encoding and decoding the values?

Answer (score 2):

For me, when typing the url, a user accidentally used a / instead of a ? to start the query parameters

e.g.:

> url.com/endpoint/parameter=SomeValue&otherparameter=Another+value

which should have been:

> url.com/endpoint?parameter=SomeValue&otherparameter=Another+value

Comment: Yes, even same for me  url.com/endpoint&parameter=SomeValue&otherparameter=AnotherValue

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurred in my application and was rather misleading.

It was thrown when I was calling an .aspx page Web Method using an ajax method call, passing a JSON array object. The Web Page method signature contained an array of a strongly-typed .NET object, OrderDetails.
The Actual_Qty property was defined as an int, and the JSON object Actual_Qty property contained "4 " (extra space character). 
After removing the extra space, the conversion was made possible, the Web Page method was successfully reached by the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with Uniform Resource Locator(URL) s there are certain [syntax standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), in this particular situation we are dealing with **Reserved Characters**.

As up to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2), Reserved Characters may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm; And asterisk(*) is a Reserved Character.

The best practice is to use [Unreserved Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) in URLs or you can try encoding it.

Keep digging :

- [HTML URL Encoding Reference (w3schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)
- [When to Encode or Decode (RFC 3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4)

Comment: This error also occurs if the reserved character in the URL is percent-encoded, e.g., `%25` instead of `%`, so IIS may return this error for a perfectly valid URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set web project's server propery as Local IIS if it is IIS Express. Be sure if project url is right and create virual directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in Azure Data Factory with the : character.

I resolved the problem **by substituting : with %3A**

as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP).

For example, I substituted

```
date1=2020-01-25T00:00:00.000Z
```

with

```
date1=2020-01-25T00%3A00%3A00.000Z
```

Comment: I'm hitting this even though they are already encoded....