# Get a complete url like http://google.com as action input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get url in my action to return the page's PageRank. I have a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PRURL",
    url: "Utility/PR/{*url}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Utility", action = "PR", url = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but whenever I go to `http://localhost:1619/Utility/PR/http://google.com` I just get a `System.Web.HttpException` that tell me `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).` I want to resolve this problem but I don't know how!

can anybody help me?

---

**Update**

I tried `[ValidateInput(false)]` but it doesn't resolved the problem!
the action is this:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public string PR(string url)
{        
    return GooglePageRank.PRChecker.PR(url);
}
```

---

**Update2**
by adding

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

the problem didn't resolved! :(

**finally**
the error resolved but the url changed from `http://google.com` to `http:/google.com` and I asked for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853025/input-url-like-http-site-com-changes-to-http-site-com-in-action-input) and I got the answer.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add a `requestPathInvalidCharacters` attribute to `httpRuntime`

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" 
    requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?" />
```

The default value is `&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?`

Comment: thanks. It worked but the http://google.com changes to http:/google.com. I'll ask a question for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable automatic request verification.

In web.config:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
```

Or for action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult PR(...
```

And I forget about web.config. You need to add to web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Or you can encode/decode url

Comment: and where do I have to add this?

Comment: I've disabled `ValidateInput` using `[ValidateInput(false)]` but I still get the security exception!

Comment: I've also added `<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>` but `http://localhost:1619/Utility/PR/http://google.com` still shows me the exception.