# Input URL like http://example.com changes to http:/example.com in action input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I asked a question to get URL as action input [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11838840/1003464). Now I have a new problem. The passed URL to action changes from `http://example.com` to `http:/example.com`.

**I want to know why and how can I resolve the problem.**

P.S: I added this code to resolve but I think there may be another problems in future! the code is:

```
if ((url.Contains(":/")) && !(url.Contains("://")))
{
    url = url.Replace(":/", "://");
}
```

Comment: on an unrelated note, it looks like your code is replacing all depressed/undecided faces with slanty scared-looking faces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser (or server) is replacing a double slash (illegal) with a single one.
Try it,

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853025//input-url-like-http-site-com-changes-to-http-site-com-in-action-input`

(in Chrome) goes to:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853025/input-url-like-http-site-com-changes-to-http-site-com-in-action-input`

If I were you, I would remove the http:// from your path and add it later.

`http://localhost:1619/Utility/PR/example.com/`

Then, `url = "http://" + url;`

If you might get secure urls, add that to the route `/http/example.com` or `/https/example.com`

Answer (score 2):

use regex:

```
string src = @"http://example.com";
string result = Regex.Replace(src, @"(?<=https?:/)/", "");
```

if you need to revert:

```
string src = @"http:/example.com";
string result = Regex.Replace(src, @"(?<=https?:)/(?=[^/])", @"//");
```

Comment: and do you know why it happens?

Comment: yes, my code replace href slashes in any string correctly, your code wrong if string would be like `http://google.com http:/google.com`

Comment: Thanks. I'll use your way but I'd rather to know why. sorry to not set your answer as accepted!