# how to parse something like domain name to a action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, iis-8

this is one of my routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PR",
    url: "Home/PageRank/{id*}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but when I use this url `http://localhost:56828/Home/PageRank/google.com` I'm getting 404 error.

Comment: Isn't this similar to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838840/get-a-complete-url-like-http-google-com-as-action-input?rq=1

Comment: IIS may be blocking `.com` extensions for security reasons.  Try `.org`.

Comment: @SLaks it's same with `.org`

Comment: @Learner that was about getting url with protocol. with `{it*}` in route IIS shouldn't try to find google.com file in `Home/PageRank/` folder but it seems it try to find it and repose 404 error!

Comment: The `.` in the url can cause the issue. Try having the following setting in your `Web.config` and see if it works. `<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`

Comment: @KiranChalla That worked! Thank you. Would you post an answer so I can accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` in the url can cause the issue. Try having the following setting in your Web.config and see if it works. `<system.webServer> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>`