# How do I enable special characters in MVC routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm using asp.net MVC 4.

These are my routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
         );
```

My current controller responds to the following request correctly:

`http://localhost:2020/PrivacyUrls/Details/ct14524`

How can I validate urls like these?

`http://localhost:2020/PrivacyUrls/Details/*ct14524`

`http://localhost:2020/PrivacyUrls/Details/&ct14524`

which now returns 404.

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*).

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

I thought adding this route, but it didn't help:

```
       routes.MapRoute(
         "PivacyUrl/Details",
         "PrivacyUrls/Details/{*ctid}",// URL with parameters 
         new { controller = "PrivacyUrls", action = "Details" }
         );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

Blatantly stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026291/299408

Answer (score 0):

The answer did not work for me. I had to use:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index...
```

Hope this helps others.