# Route not working if both pattern and variable contains dash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an action in a controller with the following route defined.

```
[Route(@"mycontroller/myaction/{itemId:int}-{itemSlug}"]
public ActionResult MyAction(int itemId, string itemSlug) {
  ...
}
```

It works and hits the action with proper parameters if the `itemSlug` itself does not contain a dash, but if it does, the route doesn't get hit. I don't udnerstand it, because in my opinion the correct behaviour would be to leave the rest of the dashes and process them as part of `itemSlug` if I constrain the part before the first dash to be integer.

How to overcome this issue? I would'nt like to use a different character to separate `itemId` and `itemSlug`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, [answer taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009618/how-do-i-enable-special-characters-in-mvc-routing)

---

While you could try these settings in config file

```
<system.web>
     <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
     <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

I would avoid using characters like '&' in URL path replacing them with underscores.

---

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of using such special characters. I was talking about simple dashes, which AFAIK completely valid URI characters. My problem is rather related to route parsing I guess.