# Asp.Net MVC routing not accepting & in the route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a default Asp.Net route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Nothing to special in it.

And I have my super simple default action in Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }
```

I can type the URL: http://localhost:12143/Home/Index/HanselandCratel

and it works fine but when I type in

http://localhost:12143/Home/Index/Hansel&Cratel

it doesn't

I understand & has to be encoded but when I type in:

http://localhost:12143/Home/Index/Hansel%26Cratel

it still doesn't work I get this error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
```

I am aware of setting this in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
```

but I am afraid I will have to sacrifice security when I do that.

Is there any other alternative to this? Perhaps any setting in Asp.Net?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `&` in your URL?

Comment: It seems like you're asking this same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009618/how-do-i-enable-special-characters-in-mvc-routing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am aware of setting this in web.config: `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />`

**Do not** do it, you're removing all the protection given by this request validation rule. If you want to allow <kbd>&</kbd> character then leave all the others in-place:

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />
```

> but I am afraid I will have to sacrifice security when I do that.

In this way <kbd>&</kbd> will be allowed in your request URLs. Be careful to properly validate all input parameters and to, eventually, escape them as required. Note that it should be done also with original rule in-place...

You may re-include also other characters but I'd suggest to do it only if required. You may also add new ones: sometimes I have text IDs as parameters (for AJAX GET requests) and even if I'm sure I won't ever build a SQL command concatenating strings...I usually add <kbd>'</kbd> (and few others).

> Is there any other alternative to this? Perhaps any setting in Asp.Net?

Yes, you may go back to .NET 2.0 rules but I see no reason to do it...

Comment: Thanks but if I use <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,:,\,?" /> squiggly line possibly due to <

Answer (score 0):

```
[ValidateInput(false)]          //write this
public ActionResult Index(string id)
 {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
 }

 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
 <pages validaeRequest="false" />
```

Try that 1st line. May be that will work for you.