# passing string with html tags to controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, richtextbox, wysiwyg

I'm using asp.net mvc2 and I want to implement a rich text area, and passing the contents in this textarea to controller. However, I found that since the contents of rich text area contains html tags, such as "
", it cannot be passed to controller. If I remove this html tags using regex expression, everything works well.

what can I do to pass these contents containing html tags to controller?

Comment: Please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client/6026291#6026291


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client/6026291#6026291

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 ways you can do in this case
+ Put some line of configuration into the `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
<configuration>
```

- Put one attribute (`[ValidateInput(false)]`) onto the action that you want to posting back on the server side

> ```
> public class DummyController : Controller
>     {
>         [ValidateInput(false)]
>         public ActionResult Save(FormData formData)
>         {
>             return View();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: be careful turning sitewide validation off.. It borderlines a TERRIBLE idea