# How do I send the following sample message as query string?

Tags: c#, wcf, get, query-string

sample message :login=admin&password=password&TranId=0617759203&TranType=9220

I have a WCF service with  the following method

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetSampleMethod")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSampleMethod/inputStr/{data}")]
         string GetSampleMethod(string data);
```

i am able to send just a single string /Service.svc/GetSampleMethod/inputstr/**abc** as data. When i tried  to send the sample message as data i am getting the following error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (&).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous
>   Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client (&).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9672068
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

Could anyone please help me with this? How do i need to send this type of message as query string?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6026291/1879286

Answer (score 0):

You need to HTTP encode the values you're sending in the query string. In order words, your "&TranId=0617759203" becomes (minus the space) "& amp;TranIDTranId=0617759203" so it can be sent over http.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Could you please provide me sample code. It would be helpful.

Comment: String sQueryString = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Your Query String Here");