# Method not allowed or A potential threat detected or restful wcf post data

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

Here is my wcf restful services created by me.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(  Method="GET",    
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
        UriTemplate = "GiveMenu")]

    Stream GiveMenu();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "GetOrder/{order_json}")]

     bool GetOrder(string order_json);
```

Here I can fetch data from  GiveMenu method like this :

```
http://localhost:5203/Service1.svc/GiveMenu
```

But when i am trying to post data like this :

```
http://localhost:5203/Service1.svc/GetOrder/{"order":[{"Tb_id":1,"Item_id":1,"Quantity":1,"Add_Details":"null"}]}
```

Then i said :

```
HttpException (0x80004005) : A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
```

Then i did following correction in my web config file :

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""/>
```

Then i showed be Method not allowed like this :
[image: Method Not Allowed]

What should i do to make data post work and solve this error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

As answered here : [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

You could try the following in your web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```