# How to generate an ActionLink using a query string for the Id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

My Id values can contain asterisks:

```
Controller/Edit/191354*
```

This, of course, results in a server error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)
```

I've read various posts on how to get around this, and it seems the simplest would be to pass the Id in as a query string instead:

```
Controller/Edit?id=191354*
```

If I do this in my views, I need not change anything else in my project. This is great, because embedded asterisks are a corner case and I'd prefer not to do a lot of work to get past this.

However, I'm having a terrible time try to use Html.ActionLink() in my view to generate such a link. I'm almost to the point of giving up and building the link by hand, but surely there must be a simple way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: I saw that while researching, but it doesn't answer my question, and I think changing requestPathInvalidCharacters would be overkill for this.

Comment: Do all of your ids contain an asterisk? If so, you could just remove it from the link and then add it back server side. I ralize that is a silly solution, but its quick!

Comment: No, only some. Yeah, I could encode/decode as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Action link builds according to routes, you just need to change routes to make them use query string parameter instead of part in URL.