# Requesting GET with UTC DateTime to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have the following ASP.NET WebApi controller:

```
public class FooController : ApiController 
{
    public string Get(DateTime id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

How does the request need to be formatted? I'm getting 400s (Bad Request). Can someone give me an example of a URL to `ApiController`'s `Get()` with a DateTime, please?

This will work:

```
http://localhost:2619/api/Foo/2014-09-14
```

But this will not:

```
http://localhost:2619/api/Foo/2014-09-14T18:52:00.000Z
```

And neither will encoding it:

```
http://localhost:2619/api/Foo/2014-09-14T18%3A52%3A00.000Z
```

The DateTime I send needs to be expressed as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

`:` has special meaning in URLs (port number).  You need to escape it:

`http://localhost:2619/api/Foo/2014-09-14T18%3A52%3A00.000Z`

Comment: The unencoded `:` character is allowed in the path component of a URI (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3)

Answer (score 0):

*2014-09-14T18%3A52%3A00.000Z* , *2014-09-14T18:52:00.000Z* all are worked

allow invalid characters in  web.config (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026291/286330)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>
```

and test action

```
public String testdt(DateTime? id)
{
    return id == null ? "Empty" : id.ToString();
}
```