# Passing more than one parameter to a controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to send an id to my MVC controller method, which is sent from a json call. At the end, I need to refresh the screen. This is working fine:

```
window.location.href = '/Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth/' + categoryId;
```

However, I need to send more than one parameter now. So, my controller methods takes two parameters named, and I try call my controller like this:

```
window.location.href = '/Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth/categoryId=' + categoryId + '&subCategoryId=' + subCategoryId;
```

But I get the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (&).

Is there a better way to do this - or, how do I fix this?

Comment: You are missing `?`.

Comment: Try `window.location.href = '/Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth?categoryId =' + categoryId + '&subCategoryId=' + subCategoryId;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case:

```
window.location.href = '/Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth/' + categoryId;
```

You're probally using the **default route** that is generated when you create a new project(the id is an optional param):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults);
```

Your url **doesn't** have potential XSS chars int it.

The second url is probally not supported by your server(only if you created a relevant routing) but if it is you should read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client) to solve your problem.

The best practice is to use a url like this:

```
/Controller/Action?param1=abc&param2=deg
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the power of MVC routing to help you?

Create a new route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Spending report by month",
    url : "Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth/{categoryId}/{subCategoryId}",
    defaults: new { controller =  "Reports", action = "SpendingByCategoryByMonth" },
    constraints : new { categoryId = @"\d+", subCategoryId = @"\d+" });
```

Make sure this appears before

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Then you could change the href to be:

`window.location.href = '/Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth/' + categoryId + '/' + subCategoryId;`

e.g.

`http://localhost:54313/Reports/SpendingByCategoryByMonth/1/2`

**Controller**

`public ActionResult SpendingByCategoryByMonth(int categoryId, int subCategoryId)`

No need for any `&` or `?` characters at all in the href url.

Note, I'm assuming the category Id values are `int`, if they are not, then simply remove the `constraints` section of the route mapping.