# How to Ignore Improperly Formatted Query String in Route

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting, routes

I have a problem where an external blog is incorrectly linking to the site. It's links are missing the "?" in the query string for a Google Analytics Campaign Source. This causes the .Net page to not display and error out.

Their links are missing the "?"

```
  www.example.com/seoFriendlyRoute&CS_002=123456&CS_010=[987654]
```

The problem is the **&CS_002=123456&CS_010=[987654]** without the ?.

I want the route to handle this so that it displays the page, ignores the garbage at the end (or better yet fixes it), and does not throw an error.

Can I do this with Route.Config?

Do I need to rewrite the URL? Hoping to avoid this.

I've contacted the blog to fix this, but I also want to future proof the page for other issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with the answer from here:
[Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

and removed the & from blocked characters.