# Problem with a QueryString : A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple actionMethod. I was just trying to Test the actionMethod using a QueryString but instead of returning Content i get this Error ): Yellow Screen of death ): Stated that :

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

**QueryString:**

```
http://localhost:63594/Home/LikePost/UserId=1&EntryId=1
```

**ActionMethod:**

```
// Like a Post.
public ActionResult LikePost(int UserId, int EntryId)
{
   return Content("User Id  Is  : " + UserId + "Post Id  is : " + EntryId);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: i checked that one.. @KennethK. but i can't findout my solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: Should be _http://localhost:63594/Home/LikePost?UserId=1&EntryId=1_ or _http://localhost:63594/Home/LikePost/1/1_

Comment: What's wrong with my actionMethod and QueryString.....why i am getting this ?

Comment: @Steve ): Thanks

Comment: It looks like your querystring is missing a "?".  Try popping one in between the trailing / of the address, and "UserId"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Problem was with a **QueryString**.

QueryString in Question: 
http://localhost:63594/Home/LikePost/UserId=1&EntryId=1

Corrected QueryString: http://localhost:63594/Home/LikePost?UserId=1&EntryId=1

> **I tried this :**
>
> /LikePost/...
>
> **but the Correct one was :**
>
> /LikePost?...