# Getting a potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<) at domain level

Tags: iis

I have hosted my web application at IIS like as follows.

MyDomain 
   ->Sub Domain 1
   ->Sub Domain 2 
So I am getting **a potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<) error**
at domain level
For Ex- Suppose I hit the URL as **www.MyDomain.com/<**
in this case, I am getting error.
So anyone help me on how to handle this at the domain level.

I achieved this at sub-domain level like

Answer (score 1):

Servers are hit with a URL containing an invalid character. The issue is because of “<” in the request path.

you could try to set below code in web.config file under `<system.web>` section:

```
 <pages validateRequest="false">
```

or

Look for requestPathInvalidCharacters in the config files and update it to remove "&lt" from it.

```
 <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
    </system.web>
```

[Getting "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)