# Potentially dangerous Request.Path due to doubled url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, umbraco, azure-application-insights, dangerous-request

I'm maintaining a legacy .NET 4.7.2 MVC application that uses Umbraco CMS 7.15.7. We started getting failed requests registered in Azure Application Insights with the following message

`A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).`

I've seen that it is related to requests such as these (below is a sample request that usually occurs in Application Insights logs, I've just changed the real website domain):

```
timestamp [UTC]
2021-09-28T21:50:31.1808953Z

name
GET /companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company

url
https://www.sample-site.com/companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company

success
False

resultCode
400

duration
0.1136

performanceBucket
<250ms

itemType
request
customDimensions
{"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.1')"}

operation_Name
GET /companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company

client_Type
PC

client_IP
0.0.0.0

sdkVersion
web:2.9.0-23612
```

I realise that the problem (:) is because the `url` and the `name` end up being somehow "doubled" (`https://www.sample-site.com/companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company`). My goal is not to allow such requests, but rather find the cause of them.

Here are my conclusions as to what might be causing this issue:

- The failed requests seem to occur periodically, and in bulk - every 5-10 hours. One product page never gets called twice within a bulk. This led me to believe that they might be caused by a bot, but then again the pattern isn't always clear - there will be minutes apart between two requests.
- The requests seem to occur mostly for product pages that are under a certain node in Umbraco (in this instance, the `companies` node). However, there are some product pages under that node in Umbraco that don't have the occurrence.
- The failed request contains https:/ with only one "/", which is odd and seems that this part is concatenated at some point
- The few successful requests under the  `companies`  node always have a 301 status code, which leads me to believe that the issue could be related to a broken redirect rule somewhere
- The error started occurring after we changed some content in Umbraco for certain product pages (mostly `canonicalUrl` properties of product page nodes). But then again, there are some product pages that do have the property filled out, but do not get the issue.
- I can never relate these requests to a user or session in Application Insights

I am aware that this might be too specific to debug and that this might be caused by practically anything - but I do have a feeling that it's somehow related to Umbraco, so somebody with experience in Umbraco and the knowledge how the `name` property could end up being generated as `GET /companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company` could lead me to some clues?

As additional information, here is a successfully executed request to a product page under the same node in Umbraco:

```
timestamp [UTC]
2021-09-29T07:27:54.2739984Z

name
GET /companies/second-company

url
https://www.sample-site.com/companies/second-company

success
True

resultCode
301

duration
6.4651000000000005

performanceBucket
<250ms

itemType
request
customDimensions
{"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Requests', Ver:'1.1')"}

operation_Name
GET /companies/second-company

client_Type
PC

client_IP
0.0.0.0

sdkVersion
web:2.9.0-23612
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add `ValidateRequest=false` at the top of your page.

Also,
As you are using .Net 4.7.2 you need to allow the below urls in web.config file.

```cs
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime 
            requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,*,&gt;,%,&amp;,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

I have removed the (:), the original default string is

```cs
<httpRuntime 
          requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
```

Check these [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597868) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6026291) with related discussions.

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding these properties will allow such requests? This isn't essentially what I want, since naturally "https://www.sample-site.com/companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company" is a bad request, plus it would present a security issue?

Comment: I've edited my original question stating that I want to find the cause of these requests. I apologize if the post was initially misleading.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I found the cause of the issue, so I believe it could be beneficial to others if I share it even though quite some time passed: the requests with incorrect URL were sent by an external SEO tool which we used - so the error originated outside of the system. These requests were sent by the SEO tool as they are shown here, e.g. `https://www.sample-site.com/companies/ https:/www.sample-site.com/companies/sample-company`, so they weren't malformed somewhere in the request pipeline of our system.