# unknown error :[Source] ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web

Anyone saw an error like this?

```
[Type] Warning | [Source] ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0 | [Category] Web Event | [Event] 1309 | [User] | [Computer] VM2014.conduit.local | [Description] Event code: 3005
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.
Event time: 8/21/2012 1:13:11 PM
Event time (UTC): 8/21/2012 10:13:11 AM
Event ID: 46772f5ad385469094b7e30018a6ee18
Event sequence: 949848
Event occurrence: 1589
Event detail code: 0

Application information:
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-3-129888848053228988
Trust level: Full
Application Virtual Path: /
Application Path: D:\Products\Web\AccountsServices\
Machine name: VM2014

Process information:
Process ID: 9568
Process name: w3wp.exe
Account name: CA-C-DMN\olapUser

Exception information:
Exception type: HttpException
Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)



Request information:
Request URL: http://accounts.conduit.com/https:/accounts.conduit.com/
Request path: /https:/accounts.conduit.com/
User host address: 94.127.73.24
User: 
Is authenticated: False
Authentication Type: 
Thread account name: CA-C-DMN\olapUser

Thread information:
Thread ID: 72
Thread account name: CA-C-DMN\olapUser
Is impersonating: False
Stack trace: at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: when? how? where? code lines?

Comment: Nope but its' pretty easy to google, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue is in "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client"

Often this is triggered when html or javascript is submitted through a form or in a url, though it's impossible to tell exactly from what you have posted.

Hopefully this might point your investigations in the right direction.