# URL Routing, Image Handler & "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value"

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-config, httphandler

I've been experiencing this problem now for quite sometime and have decided to try and get to the bottom of it once and for all by posting the question here for some thought. I have an image handler in a .net 4 website located here:

https://www.amadeupurl.co.uk/ImageHandler.ashx?i=3604
(actual domain removed for privacy)

Now this works fine and serves an image from the web server without problem, I say without problem because if I access the URL it works fine, the image loads, no exception is generated. However someone did visit this exact URL yesterday and an exception was raised along the following lines:

```
Exception Generated
Error Message:
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
Stack Trace:
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

Technical Information:
DATE/TIME: 23/01/2013 03:50:01
PAGE: www.amadeupurl.co.uk/ImageHandler.ashx?i=3604
```

I understand the error message, thats not a problem I just don't understand why it being generated here, to make things worse I'm unable to replicate it, like I said I click the link the image loads, no exception. I am using URL routing and registered the handler to be ignored in case this was causing an issue with the following code:

```
routes.Ignore("{resource}.ashx")
```

I'm not sure why else I would be getting the error or what else to try.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Asp.Net 4.0+ comes with a very strict built-in request validation, part of it is the potential dangerous characters in the url which may be used in XSS attacks. Here are default invalid characters in the url :

`< > * % & : \ ?`

You can change this behavior in your config file:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,%,&,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

Or get back to .Net 2.0 validation:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

A very common invalid character is `%`, so if by any chance (attack, web-crawlers, or just some non-standard browser) the url is being escaped you get this:

```
www.amadeupurl.co.uk/ImageHandler.ashx/%3Fi%3D3604
```

instead of this:

```
www.amadeupurl.co.uk/ImageHandler.ashx/?i=3604
```

Note that `%3F` is the escape character for `?`. The character is considered invalid by Asp.Net request validator and throws an exception:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).
```

Though in the error message you see the unescaped version of the character (%3F) which is `?` again

[Here's a good article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) on Request Validation and how to deal with it

Comment: Thanks Kamyar, a very insightful bit of reading, I can finally put this beast to sleep..

Comment: When using requestPathInvalidCharacters and you get the following error, use requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,>,*,%,&amp;,\,?" instead:

Character '<', hexadecimal value 0x3c is illegal in XML attribute values.

Comment: @SteveA, what you said is used here, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597868/2218697)

Comment: I'll add that I was getting this error because my requests were to  http://example.com&request=param rather than http://example.com?request=param with a "?". Dumb mistake :P

Comment: Is there no way to allow these characters for a particular controller action instead of allowing it site wide?

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced this issue but for me, I accidentally typed & instead of the ? in the URL

for example:

example.com/123123&parameter1=value1&paameter2=value2

but in actual it has to be:

example.com/123123?parameter1=value1&paameter2=value2

Answer (score 0):

A super old thread but this works:

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", new { @myParameterName = "MyParameterValue" });
```

You can also add the controller name after action name if the request is going to a different controller and also add more query string parameters simply by chaining them with commas between.