# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:) - angular http request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).]   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9560004   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

**My code:**

```
 public List<GetPlayersSiteGoalViewModel> GetPlayers(string teamUrl)
 {
     var playersSiteGoal = new List<GetPlayersSiteGoalViewModel>();
     return playersSiteGoal;
 }
```

**Angular Service Method:**

```
 dataBaseService.getPlayers = function (param) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: getBaseUrl() + dataBaseService.apiController + '/GetPlayers/' + param.TeamUrl
                });
            };
```

**Update :**

`param.TeamUrl`:

`http://www.goal.com/en-us/teams/italy/juventus/1242?ICID=SP_TN_82`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here may be of some help: [URL Routing, Image Handler & "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475913/url-routing-image-handler-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value)

It looks like `?` is marked by ASP.NET as an invalid character in your URL.

**Edit**

Going back and re-reading the error message, it looks like `:` is the source of your problem.  While I don't see it in the url you pass, it looks like it is getting added to the url somewhere (maybe by `getBaseUrl()`?).  Even if you fix that, I assume you would get another error with `?` based on the invalid list supplied by the answer in the linked question.

**Edit 2**

You can fix it by either adding : and ? to the `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters` property of the web.config as that link shows, or do what Scott Hanselman shows in the link at the bottom of that answer: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Answer (score 1):

i found.

replace this :

```
dataBaseService.getPlayers = function (param) {
                return $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: getBaseUrl() + dataBaseService.apiController + '/GetPlayers/' + param.TeamUrl
                });
            };
```

with this :

```
 dataBaseService.getPlayers = function (param) {
                return $http({
                    url: getBaseUrl() + dataBaseService.apiController + '/GetPlayers',
                    params: { teamUrl: param.TeamUrl }
                });
            };
```