# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to fetch some English Translation of Quran from `quran.com` for a university project using the following link:

http://quran.com/quran/ajax?s=1&sA=1&eA=8&l=12C6

This link when entered in browser returns proper results but when I try to use this link in my Angular method I get the error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)
```

**Angular Method:**

```
Qt.Link = "http://quran.com/quran/ajax?s=1&sA=1&eA=8";
Qt.GetTranslation = function () {
        $http.get("/"+Qt.Link).success(function (result) {
            Qt.display = result;
        }).error(function (data) {
            toastr["error"](data);

        });
    };
```

After searching on the internet I found out that this is because of some invalid characters in the URL or because of not passing the parameter correctly like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570506/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client-an).

- If the link works in the browser why doesn't it work with the Angular method?
- How can I fix this?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: could you try logging exactly what's in the variable Qt.Link? (before doing the http.get)

Comment: sorry my bad, updating the question...

Comment: are you sure your & and ? don't get escaped? you might have to pass the s, A, eA and I as get parameters `{eA:8,s:1,sA:1,l:"12C6"}`

Comment: @MichaelDibbets yes I am trying that..

Comment: What Michael Dibbets said, and also try removing the "/" in front of Qt.Link.

Comment: @StevenLemmens I tried removing the "/" but it didn't work and I got no response...

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi CORS Error in the console after removing the `/` ?

Comment: @Hacketo I get this error after removing the "/" in the console:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://quran.com/quran/ajax?s=1&sA=1&eA=8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3855' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What `$http.get("/"+Qt.Link)` will try to load is:

```
/http://quran.com/quran/ajax?s=1&sA=1&eA=8
```

That leading `/` means it will try to load it **from your server**.

To get `http://quran.com/quran/ajax?s=1&sA=1&eA=8`, remove the `/`.

Note that if this is client-side (as it seems to be), you may run into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which only allows XHR requests within an origin unless the target of the request specifically supports [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) and shares with *your* origin (or all origins).

If that service is meant to be used from *client-side* code, they'll have a page telling you how to do it (JSONP or similar). If it's not, you'll have to send a query to **your** server with that as a parameter, and have your **server** do the request to `quran.com` and then send you back the response.