# Handling "extra" params in ASP.Net MVC5 routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this path that I need to handle:

```
http://mpdev.website.com/Account/ExternalLogOn?LogonTicket=c3792319c8711a0dd465bbd6f6b31ea913b42db7&PID=1137565&ReturnUrl=/Home/CompReq?EC=151120TXAM
```

The ExternalLogon action in the Account Controller automatically logs the user in based on a check between the LogonTicket and the PID. Then it is supposed to redirect to the ReturnUrl.

How would I fix the /Home/CompReq route to handle the EC parameter and how to modify the Action in the Home Controller?

I have only one route in my RouteConfig:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

This link works perfectly but I know I don't have any params on it.

```
http://mpdev.website.com/Account/ExternalLogOn?LogonTicket=c3792319c8711a0dd465bbd6f6b31ea913b42db7&PID=1137565&ReturnUrl=/Home/MyInfo
```

Home Controller Action  definition is like this:

```
public ActionResult CompReq(string eventcode)
```

ExternalLogon definition:

```
ExternalLogOn(string LogonTicket, int? PID, string User, string EC, String State, string ReturnUrl)
```

Comment: What does your ReturnUrl parameter of ExternalLogon action contains when you pass the path with the 'EC' part ?

Comment: Not getting what you are asking

Comment: Your action called 'ExternalLogon' probably has 3 input parameter; LogonTicket, PID and ReturnUrl right ? what does ReturnUrl contains when you call it with your problematic path ?

Comment: It contains what is supposed to be in there `/Home/CompReq?EC=151120TXAM` but then I get an exception: `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).`

Comment: well two solutions for you, either you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475913/url-routing-image-handler-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value
or you could store into your database, next to your LogonTicket, the returnUrl value

Comment: Nothing stored in DB. I updated with ExternalLogon definition.

Comment: Trying to set the requestPathInvalidChars in Web.config won't work as `<` is an invalid char in XML.

Comment: Was able to set `requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,&amp;,*,%,:,;,\,?,%"` but still got same exception as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReturnUrl value should be url encoded:

```
http://mpdev.website.com/Account/ExternalLogOn?LogonTicket=c3792319c8711a0dd465bbd6f6b31ea913b42db7&PID=1137565&ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FCompReq%3FEC%3D151120TXAM
```

CompReq action should have same function parameter name as query parameter name:

```
public ActionResult CompReq(string EC)
```

ExternalLogon action should have proper parameters:

```
ExternalLogOn(string LogonTicket, int? PID, string ReturnUrl)
```

In ExternalLogOn you do a redirect to ReturnUrl param:

```
return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
```

Comment: You should have only one "?" char in url. That's why you should encode query parameters value (If you use UrlHelper methods to create url, MVC already handels that for you)

Comment: even URLEncoding the ? will cause the same exception. I have fixed it by moving the parameter into the first part of the URL, See the EC parameter in the ExternalLogon definition?

Comment: just encoding '?' is not enough. you have to encode entire query parameter value: /Home/CompReq?EC=151120TXAM. If you open first url in my answer, do you still get "potentially dangerous value" exception?

Comment: As I stated, I've moved on, no more issue that I moved the EC parameter outside the ReturnUrl.