# ModalDialog - A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client

Tags: javascript, iis, sharepoint, web-config

Add following code to Sharepoint 2013 page:

```
<a href=”javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('http://microsoft.com', null, 100, 100);” >microsoft</a>
```

On click I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:). 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
 Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
Source Error: 
 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +12353567
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +166

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34274
```

I have

```
<location path="_vti_bin/EwaInternalWebService.json">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <clear />
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="_vti_bin/DynamicGridContent.json">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
      <webServices>
        <protocols>
          <clear />
        </protocols>
      </webServices>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="_vti_bin/CrossDomainAjax.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>

<pages 
            enableSessionState="false"
            enableViewState="true" 
            enableViewStateMac="true"
            validateRequest="false" 
            clientIDMode="AutoID"
        pageParserFilterType="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPPageParserFilter, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
        asyncTimeout="7"
    >
```

in both **web.config** files (in **VirtualDirectories** and in **CONFIG** folders).
I've also tried to use "/_layouts/MyPage.aspx" as a URL with same result.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use relative path. The error message say: *A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).*. Notice the **(:)** I think the error are the **:**. Check also this [Stackoverflow Article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475913/url-routing-image-handler-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value)

Comment: I also tried "/_layouts/MyPage.aspx" and had (:) in error message