# Customize "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client" error without ASP.Net application

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

When deploying a single html page on a Windows Azure web app, I noticed some of the default IIS behaviors for ASP.Net still apply, even if there is no actual ASP.Net application deployed on the server. The specific case I don't understand is if the client enter an invalid addresss like `https://www.mysuperwebsite.com/>`. By default, IIS consider this address as unsecure (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475913/url-routing-image-handler-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value#answer-14489483) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)), which is totally fine to me.

The problem I have from that point is **I want to display my own error page**, not the default one from IIS.

As my site contains no ASP.Net related stuff, I was on the impression that only the `httpErrors` section of the `web.config` applies in my case. But with the following config, I wasn't able to display my error page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File" defaultPath="error.html">
            <remove statusCode="400"/>
            <error statusCode="400" responseMode="File" path="error.html"/>
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The only way I got it to work was by adding the next section:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="error.html" />
</system.web>
```

But from my understanding `customErrors` section is dediacted to handle errors generated by ASP.Net code, which I don't have in my case...

- I confirmed with postman the error code returned by IIS in that case is 400 - bad request.
- I also tested my error paged configured in `httpErrors` by creating a folder on the web app and trying to list its content: in that case the `httpErrors` section is driving the displayed error page.
- Files for simple reproduction available [here](https://github.com/ggirard07/TestIISErrors).