# Need an explanation on behaviour of WebApi method with string paremeter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have `WebApi` method with string parameter:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> Get(string stuff)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{stuff}",
    defaults: new { stuff= RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

If I am calling the method like that:
`http://localhost:13892/api/servce?stuff=https://mysite.com/bla?g=1` **- all good**

**but if I go** `http://localhost:13892/api/servce/https://mysite.com/bla?g=1` **- getting error:** `A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).`

I **know how to fix that error** but I am wondering why it is happening? **Why in first case I am do not getting that error**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple explanation would be that the character : contained in the parameter is not allowed as part of the URL, but is perfectly legal to use in the querystring

Please note that this is possibly a dupliacate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)