# How to encode file name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I use file name to save that in the database. but I get some error when I want to download some files that have some character like: `"& , # "`

The errors are :

> bad request

or

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (&)

This is an example of file name:
**03. &  Love &  # m.mp3**

And this is my code:

```
    download_link.HRef = "upload/fm/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["mu_file"];
```

How can I encode or validate the file name by a **safe** way.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client ?

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding it with [HTMLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) and then you can decode it later with [HTMLDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For encoding and decoding please refer following links

[Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and for [Decoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx)