# Url Encoded Asterisk

Tags: c#, .net

If I pass a string as a parameter to Url.Encode, .NET chooses not to url encode the character.

So...

```
Url.Action("A", "C", new { id = "1*1" }
```

...would create the url http://mysite/C/A/1*1

However, clicking this link causes .NET to reject the parameter and throws the exception...

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*).
```

If I change the URL (in chrome) to a url encoded version...

```
http://mysite/C/A/1%2A1
```

... if still throws the same error?

How can I ensure the URLs created by .NET on one page are allowed on another page?

Comment: To be clear, the URL is not being created by *.NET*, it is being created by *you*.

Comment: Indirect solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8597868/613130

Comment: You can't have an asterisk in the path. The accepted answer to the linked question is actually a good one. Don't use such strings in the path, put them in the query string. Change your route

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to a querystring parameter and all is now good.