# How to catch "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)" to avoid web role crash?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-cloud-services

My MVC 5 web application running on Azure Cloud Service crashed with an unhandled exception "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)".

The cause for this crash was some third party (maybe malicious) hit my endpoints with url:
http://myExampleHost.com/m:443/templates

The colon in the url cannot pass the path validation.

Some answers ([A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)) suggest change the validate rules. However, out of security concerns, we may not want to compromise on this.

The ideal behavior for it that: we catch the exception, log it and return some error messages without crashing. How should we do that?

A more general question on this would be: how to catch an exception before the request hits controllers in MVC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The ideal behavior for it that: we catch the exception, log it and return some error messages without crashing. How should we do that?

Per my understanding, you could leverage the `Application_Error` event to capture unhandled exception(s) within ASP.NET. Here is my test, you could refer to it:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    var exception=Server.GetLastError();
    var httpException = exception as HttpException ?? new HttpException(500, "Internal Server Error", exception);
    var jsonResponse = new
    {
        Message = exception.Message,
        StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode(),
        StackTrace=httpException.StackTrace
    };
    httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    httpContext.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonResponse));
    httpContext.Response.End();
}
```

[image]

**Note:** You could also redirect to a specific error page.

Moreover, you could leverage the `customErrors` in web.config and catch the error page for the specific HTTP error code. Also, you could check the HTTP status code under the `Application_EndRequest` event and write your custom response, details you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717628/asp-net-mvc-404-error-handling). Additionally, I would recommend you follow [Demystifying ASP.NET MVC 5 Error Pages and Error Logging](https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging) for more details about error handling.

Comment: I like what you did, as we do something very similar by emailing the errors to ourselves and displaying a generic error to the user. How can we specifically catch this error? We recently found that we needed to catch `HttpRequestValidationException` specifically for certain other functions and want to find a way to catch this error specifically too.

Comment: I detect this exception if ErrorCode is E_FAIL/0x80004005/-2147467259 and StackTrace contains "ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig". I don't just check the message as I fear it may be language dependent?