# How to allow asp.net passwords to include special characters like "<" and '">"

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords, special-characters

How to make asp.net to allow the **less than**(<) and **greater than**(>) symbols along with other special symbols to be included in the password field?

I have tried setting the page request validation settings but I can't afford to compromise on security. Still I want the '<' and '>' symbols to be allowed in password fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only turn off request validation for entire pages; not for single controls. If you want to allow these characters in passwords, you'll have to turn the validation off on the entire page, and take extra care that other input fields are protected against XSS and the like.