# PHP/HTML: a potential dangerouse value Request.Path had been detected from the client (<)

Tags: php, html

When I try to create an account on my site the following error message is sent:

> a potential dangerous value Request. Path had been detected from the
>   client (<).

I have no clue why this happens. Any one that has a clue? (my piece of code is below):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsLDC.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (\*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: While I commend your use of `htmlspecialchars`, I must point out that `https://example.com/your_page_here.php?hax=' onclick='alert("XSS!")` will still work. Better to just use `<form action="" ...>` if you want a postback like this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<` symbol in a url, which is not exactly valid. It seems to be the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5967103/3972886).