# How to pass Date and time for HTTP GET API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restful-url, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to pass Date and time to HTTP GET API. It works well with just date.
But I get following error when i try to pass time along with it.

"A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)."

The url is something like this
"http://localhost:49123/api/books/2000-01-31T00%3A00%3A00"

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client look at this.

Comment: URL-encode your time parameter. The reason for the exception is the `:` in the time parameter

Comment: even with time encoded, i am getting error. I have mentioned the URL in the question

Answer (score 0):

Usually this exception is thrown when the URL indeed contains a dangerous character like a "*", "&", "?".

Use some kind of urlencoding. It should be 
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_urlencode.asp