# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I have this request https://192.xxx.x.x/%3cscript%3e_q_q=%27%29%28%27%3c/script%3e

After making it on my server, I have this:
[image]

How can I display a more friendly message instead?
Note: I have my asp.net c# application hosted here on: https://192.xxx.x.x/Myapp

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Are you looking to serve up a more friendly error page for yourself? Or show something like an "oops, error has occurred page for users"?

Comment: I am not sure you have to censor your IP, a _great majority_ of us have the exact same local address(es) haha

Comment: Do you want to make the error not happen anymore?  Or just have a better looking page when it breaks (i.e not fixing the problem)

Comment: @Zac something like "Ops, error has occurred" would be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You could first [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8597868/1399567) the built-in ASP.NET middleware that throws this `HTTPException` and then add your own [ASP.NET](https://dzimchuk.net/understanding-aspnet-5-middleware/) or [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) middleware that handles inspecting the request path for dangerous characters and performing a custom action (like throwing a different exception, redirecting to a custom error URL, etc).