# IIS URL Rewrite - A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

Tags: iis

My client is trying to access the URL with triple slash (:///), however, the error occurred as shown in the title. They do not want any modification to the URL, so is there any way for the triple slash to be accepted?

I do not have much information regarding it, but they tried few solutions they found from the web in modifying some parts in IIS config but it still doesn't work.

Comment: What like is the URL address you are accessing?

Comment: Hello, it's something like this: (http:// xxx.xxx.x.xxx/activity/documents.w3p;pioiid=ema%3A%2F%2F%2F45e6b900-8929-11d4-b772-0050) So, we think %3A%2F%2F%2F (:///) is the issue

Comment: Do you want to rewrite 3A%2F%2F%2F to %3A%2F%2F%2F (:///)?

Comment: No, we want the IIS to accept %3A%2F%2F%2F (which converts to :/// in character)

Comment: I think this is IIS and does not allow to appear in the rewrite path (:///). There is a similar issue in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client