# Allow plus sign in URL with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I need to be able to allow the "+" sign for certain actions in a controller. I am building a tag filtering engine that allows something like this (ie. stackoverflow) : /Stuff/Tagged/tag-name-1+tag-name-2+other-tag

I know I can set `allowDoubleEscaping="true"` in the web.config, but it is not best practices for security reasons.

I am guessing there is a way using maybe a custom filer or some other registry in the global.asax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StackOverflow is probably treating the + as a whitespace. Most likely they map the route `/Stuff/Tagged/{*tags}` and call `string.split()` on the tags. This actually works out great if you don't allow whitespace in your tags.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. But the only way for IIS7 to allow the `+` sign in the url is to allowDoubleEscaping in the web.config which may pose a security risk.

Comment: Its probably a bit overly paranoid, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous

Comment: You're right, it is overly paranoid. For others, the solution Wyatt went over is what I'm currently using and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

`+` means whitespace in an url. You should URL encode them:

```
/Stuff/Tagged/tag-name-1%2Btag-name-2%2Bother-tag
```

Comment: I'm aware of that... but it is not visually appealing and does not serve the purpose in this case. Nowadays more sites are using the plus sign in the URL for what it means, like Stack Overflow does for its tags.

Comment: It is not possible, because [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/5_BNF.html) standards specify + represents space in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple replace:

```
string url = Url.Action("Index", "YourController");
url = url.Replace("%2b", "+");
```