# Routing does not recognize route if space appear in route value as '+' char

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

I faced the following problem. May be someone found this strange behavior too.

I have the following route definition in my global.asax.cs:

```
routes.Add(new Route("/module/{searchTerm}", new RouteValueDictionary { {"controller", "Module"}, {"action", "Index"} }, null, new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

So, nothing special, from the first point of view, but problem appear when space appear in search term as `+` sign.

For instance we try to open a link:

```
http://[myserver]/module/some%20search%20term
```

In this case everything is ok and it redirects us to a correct action, but in case if the link looks like:

```
http://[myserver]/module/some+search+term
```

I got an error stated that there are no routes that are match the URL provided.

By the way, I can't reproduce this issue on ASP.NET development server. It appear only on IIS. Probably someone did have such problems?

Comment: By Dev server, do you mean local IIS when run through the IDE or do you mean IISExpress?

Comment: It's a small local server that comes with Visual Studio.

Comment: In that case, you mean IISExpress which has it's own config files for each user account. The interesting thing is that it's the same core as full-blown IIS so functionally they should be identical. I don't know what's causing the difference but I'd start by looking in `C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\IISExpress\config` and seeing if there's anything in there that would account for it.

Comment: No, I even do not have an IISExpress installed on my computer, I tested it on Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server.

Comment: That means Cassini (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx) which is being replaced with IISExpress as it's not like-for-like with IIS.

Comment: Yes, I know that Cassini is replaced in VS 2012 by IISExpress.

Answer (score 1):

- Percent encoding in the path section of a URL is expected to be decoded, but
- any + characters in the path component is expected to be treated literally.

To be explicit: + is only a special character in the query component.

[RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738) (as modified by 2396 and 3986) defines the scheme (http:), authority (//server.example.com), and path (/myfile/mypage.htm) component, and does not define any special meaning for the + character.

Comment: Ok you're must be right, but why it does works in ASP.NET development server? That's the question...

Answer (score 0):

`+` sign is a delimiter of segments. Segments being scheme, authority, path and query.

From the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain 
>   special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
>   their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>   purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>   reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>   forming the URI.
>
> ```
>   reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","
> ```
>
> The "reserved" syntax class above refers to those characters that
>   are    allowed within a URI, but which may not be allowed within a
>   particular component of the generic URI syntax; they are used as
>   delimiters of the components described in Section 3.

Apparently, this was badly implemented in Cassini.

Answer (score 0):

- sign in path part of the URL does not work if double escaping is prohibited in IIS settings. It's a part of request filtering policy. But it could be configured in web.config
  [Is Enabling Double Escaping Dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous)

When I enabled it in my web.config everything started to work fine.