# Why might I get a double escape sequence error in mobile chrome but not desktop chrome?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, google-chrome, mobile, escaping

When attempting to make an ajax post from my angular web page on a mobile device, I receive the following error:

```
The request contained a double escape sequence and request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny double escape sequences.
```

However, when attempting to make the same post from my desktop, the post works as expected and I receive no error. I have tested this in chrome and IE.

Here is the ajax post if it helps:

```
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
url: baseApiAddress + 'mobile/' + customerPhone, //+ $scope.mobileId,
method: 'PUT',
file: file, // or list of files: files for html5 only
contentType: "application/json"
})
```

I am able to prevent this error by adding the following to my `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="True"/>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm reading why this may be dangerous [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous).

Why does this error occur on mobile when it is not present on desktop? Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need any additional information from me.

Comment: can you console log  - (baseApiAddress + 'mobile/' + customerPhone) and show exactly the url that is being applied?

Comment: @Kyle I had no way to debug in mobile so I just threw a `alert(baseApiAddress + 'mobile/' + customerPhone)` in there and it quickly revealed the problem. I forgot that I have a function that adds `+1` to the user's number and this causes the URL to end up looking like: `http://fake.base.api/mobile/+15554443333`. When testing in the desktop, I manually entered the URL and did not add the `+1`. This should fix it, thank you for the help.

Comment: Great!  yea, it seems that the plus sign is the root cause for this specific error message in most cases I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake and forgot about a function that added `+1` to the front of user's phone numbers, which were later used in constructing the URL. The `+` character is what causes IIS to throw the double escaping error (More info [here](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/iis7-rejecting-urls-containing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous)). Once I remove this `+` character, the error no longer shows up. This error wasn't present in the desktop version because I manually entered the URL and did not add a `+` character when testing.