# Url rewrite return 404 error when spaces replaced with + in umbraco

Tags: asp.net, umbraco7

I need to rewrite a url in umbraco.  It is currently working if i leave the spaces in.  However i want to remove the spaces and replace them with a + for more user friendly urls without a %20.

So this is working.

```
/For-Sale/6_24-Hunter Street-KELVIN GROVE-4059
```

But this does not.  And umbraco just tells me that the page cannot be found. 404 error.

```
/For-Sale/6_24-Hunter+Street-KELVIN+GROVE-4059
```

This is the umbraco url rewrite rule that i am using.

```
<add name="SaleRule"
     virtualUrl="^~/For-Sale/(.*)"
     destinationUrl="~/Result/Item?type=For-Sale&amp;address=$1"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

Any idea on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that experience this issue here is how i resolved it.

I found the answer in the following post - 
[Is Enabling Double Escaping Dangerous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous)

To allow the + symbol in the url i needed to set the following in the web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The Url rewriting rules i had in Umbraco where correct.