# Why does IIS Express consider this URL has a double escape sequence?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis-express, urlencode

http://localhost:8084/views/mask17/Part/MOTOR.SUB_MOTOR.112/Cl.1%20DIV.2%20Gr.%20C%2BD

The last part of the path is unencoded

```
Cl.1 DIV.2 Gr. C+D
```

---

Background: SPA frontend and .NET Core WebAPI backend.

One controller  has this declaration

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/views/maske17/Part/{NodeId}/{DataId}")]
    public virtual IActionResult InfoGet([FromRoute][Required] string NodeId, [FromRoute]string DataId)
```

---

**Error**

Calling the above URL causes

```
HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

---

If I remove the encoding for the + between C and D the error does not happen

---

**Questions**

1. Why does IIS Express consider this URL has a double escape sequence?
2. Which part of the encoded path is the "double escape sequence"?

Comment: Did my answer below answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the `+` is the culprit. You provide a `%2B`, which is decoded twice, i.e., via the `+` character into a space character.

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453218/is-enabling-double-escaping-dangerous) and this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3580) for further details.